# Sharepoint 2010 client model. Set multiple values in taxonomy field

Tags: sharepoint-2010, taxonomy, sharepoint-clientobject, csom

How can I set multiple values in taxonomy field using client model?
For single value I use follow snippet:

```
    var item = ctx
    .get_web()
    .get_lists()
    .getByTitle('News')
    .getItemById($("#newsId").val());

    var newTag = "40;#term_title|cd1df680-fff6-4d37-a336-95a2fbc0719d";

    item.set_item("NewsTag", newTag);
    item.update();

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    });
```

it works fine for single value.

I have tried to use newTag variable as array and tryed to concatenate two strings `{id};#{title}|{guid}` with `;` separator but it does not work.

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the right way to set multiple values. Actually the delimiter is combination of semicolon and sharp ";#" not just a semicolon ";"